# Unable to connect DB2 with PHP

Tags: php, db2

I tried to connect to a remote DB2 database located on IBM AS400 server.
I'm running debian 10 with PHP7.3 and nginx.
I installed correctly DSDriver and ibm_db2 php extension with pecl install ibm_db2 command.

Here's my php code to test connection :

```
<?php

$driver = '{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}';
$database = 'MY_DB';
$user = 'USERNAME';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$hostname = 'MY_IP';
$port = 50000;


$conn_string = 'DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;';
$conn_string .= 'HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;';
$conn_string .= 'UID=$user;PWD=$password;';

try {
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');

if (! $conn) 
{
    echo db2_conn_errormsg();
}

else { 
    echo "Conn OK ";
}

db2_close($conn);
}

catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
}


?>
```

The result is  :

"Connection failed."

What am I missing, what could be wrong ?

Comment: Additionally, your code needs to use a try { } catch {} around any calls to Db2, and in the exception handler it needs to echo the e->getMessage() for exception e. This will give details of the error, this is basic programming.

Comment: When i used a try { } catch {}, I get these error [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1337N  The service "$port" was not found. SQLCODE=-1337PHP.
Port 50 000 is working because when i connect with JAVA JBDC based client, I could connect to remote DB2.

Comment: I can run SQL command on port 50 000 because I can connect with JDBC on DB2... (but not with PHP)... You can see my new code, I edited my post.

Comment: JDBC is connecting to DB2 because when I enter credentials (including with port 50000) into RazoSQL or into IBM i Access Clients Solution, I can make SQL request.

Comment: Moreover IP address and hostname are identical between JDBC and PHP

Comment: What's the version of your unixODBC? It needs to be 2.2.13 or higher. Have you configured it to work with 'IBM i access' for Linux, and does isql work at the bash shell to connect to Db2-for-i?   (If you can get isql connecting to your Db2 for i with IBM i access , then PHP should work). The regular IBM Db2 DSDriver *will not* work with i-series for ODBC *unless* you *either* go via a Db2-connect server (or add a license for DsClient for i-serieS) , but the 'IBM i Access ' product *will* work.

Comment: When you get the 'IBM i access' for Linux working with unixODBC, change your code to specify *its* driver name, which is `DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};`

Comment: unixODBC is version 2.3.6 and isql doesn't work at the bash shell

Answer (score 0):

Your question mentions "DSDriver" and Db2 for i-series, and your code example shows `'DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};`

If you mean the IBM Db2 Data Server driver then this cannot connect via ODBC to Db2 for i-series unless *either* you connect via a pre-existing Db2-connect gateway, or you add a Db2-connect personal licence to your workstation.

If you installed on Debian the 'IBM i access' for Linux product (64 bit) this product will let you use unixODBC to connect to Db2-for-i, as long as your unixODBC version is a certain minimum level ( 2.2.13 or higher) and your PHP code uses the correct driver name which is `DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};`. IBM mentions the unixODBC version dependency in its [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions), which may change from time to time,

After configuring unixODBC with the IBM i access product, it is helpful to get the isql tool to connect to the Db2-for-i before trying PHP, as it will verify the connectivity,port,credentials along with the ODBC interface. It may be easier to troubleshoot that before programming with PHP.  If you get the isql working correctly with Db2-for-i, then PHP should just work as long as your code specifies the correct driver name.

Pay attention to the documented restrictions with the unixODBC interface to Db2 and the differences between the Windows driver and Linux driver that IBM describes in the [redbook](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/as400/products/clientaccess/solutions/IBMiACS_LinuxAppPkg_Install_Usage_Guide.pdf) for this topic.

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand anything.
I must connect to a remote DB2.
I got a debian 10 / PHP7.3 (my pc) and the remote DB2 is running on AS400.

Comment: Try harder. Install the latest 64-bit `IBM i access for linux` on debian, and configure it and unixODBC per instruction in the redbook.